# In Area 51, Reputation and badges of Documentation are the same as Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, flair, area-51

Going through the [list of users in a Area 51 proposal I committed to](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/98807/dream-interpretation), I noticed that my profile shows a network reputation of 223K. This looks way over the [real one](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/2251762.png) (currently 119K):

[image: fedorqui]

So this seems to be taking into account the Stack Overflow account twice:

[image: fedorqui]

And indeed this happens:

[image]

Comment: I would be happy with 223K reputation :)

Comment: I really am! Now, I am about to melt all these extra badges I got and make me a necklace :D

Comment: Did you just receive a bunch of badges too? Seconds ago.

Comment: @PatrickHofman We're fixing the badge thing. Not sure what's up with the rep counting here, though, gonna dig.

Comment: @PatrickHofman yes, for example 5 silver [Documentation Beta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6157/documentation-beta)

Comment: @AdamLear is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6158/documentation-pioneer) okay. He got that badge multiple times.

Comment: Posted already in [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281376/312043)

Comment: @Arulkumar oh, thanks! I had also posted it [there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281502/209901) (so it would had been a duplicate of yours) and was suggested to post it here, since it seems to be Documentation related, which is in the scope of [SO].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things came together to make this possible.

Area 51 periodically pulls a list of sites through the API and updates its own internal records. So it happily created a record in its Sites table for docs-beta, even though there was no actual site proposal to go along with it.

I didn't realize that happened, so didn't flip the State that record to indicate that the site was no longer in private beta. (That part apparently doesn't get updated via the API. It just checks for new sites, IIRC, not doing a diff on what's going on state-wise.)

But on top of that, Area 51 also maintains a list of site associations for each user in JSON format, including site's id, the user's id on that site, and the user's reputation. This is where this gets fun: because of the site record created above, A51 dutifully made requests to the docs-beta site asking for users' reputation... and we just as dutifully redirected those requests to Stack Overflow. So basically everyone with an SO profile ended up with an effectively duplicate association record, regardless of whether they even joined the docs-beta site or not.

Fun stuff.

Site record has been updated in Area 51 and associations regenerated, so everything should be back to normal now.

Comment: Maybe it is a caching problem, but my rep in Area51 still shows SOx2 + the other sites rep ([an example](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810?phase=commitment)).

Comment: @fedorqui Hard-refresh perhaps? This is what I see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0OS2o.png

Comment: I wish I had that rep :) Mine is actually [here](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/2251762.png). So the icons are fine, only that the rep and badges still counts Stack Overflow twice.

Comment: Ohh, I see what you mean. The rep number, not the site list. Derp derp, looking.

Comment: Sorry, yes. I wasn't very descriptive :) To summarize: the list of sites is fine, the badges and reputation are still counted twice.

Comment: @fedorqui Ahhh nothing quite like running commands against a prod DB on Friday morning to wake you up. :) Should be all fixed up now. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Haha this is better than five coffees on a row, an adrenaline rush! Well done, many thanks. Now I will have to work hard to reach the rep I used to have :D