# SO and Documentation reputation (and badges) are calculated twice on Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, reputation, area-51

The question is about Stack Overflow reputation, so I decided to ask it here.

On Area 51 my reputation from several Stack Exchange sites is showing this way:

[image]

I thought that Stack Overflow and Documentation reputation was the same thing, but on Area 51 they are shown in different labels. Moreover, they are summarized as independent, so I have there almost twice of the actual Stack Overflow reputation amount. I also noticed that badges are calculated twice too.

Is this a bug?

### Update

I found related questions ([this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328407/in-area-51-reputation-and-badges-of-documentation-are-the-same-as-stack-overflo?rq=1) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281376/wrong-documentation-beta-score-in-area-51)), but they don't contains concrete answers about if this situation with reputation is normal or not.

Comment: Now it is solved: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334169/

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks, you can post this as answer.

Comment: In fact I would propose to close this one as a duplicate to that. If it was the same issue, I think it is fair to do that :)

Comment: @fedorqui I agree, should I add tag _status-completed_?

Comment: Yes! I do not know if we are allowed to do so, but I just tried to :) Edit: no, I cannot :/ _"status-completed" can only be used by moderators_, it says.

Comment: @fedorqui I had the same message, so I just flagged question with request to add this tag.